# PowerShell script works when run manually, but fails creating word.application object when initiated by Ansible?

Tags: powershell, ansible

I have a PowerShell script I'm kicking off via Ansible using the `community.windows.win_psexec` module. Here's what the task looks like:

```yaml
- name: Running my-script.ps1
  community.windows.win_psexec:
    executable: D:\Repos\my-repo\ansible\roles\PsExec\files\PsExec.exe
    command: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File "D:\Repos\my-repo\my-script.ps1" -param1 {{ param1_value }} -param2 {{ param2_value }} -switchParam
    elevated: yes
    interactive: yes
  no_log: false
```

The `my-script.ps1` script kicks off another PowerShell script which, in turn, kicks off a third PowerShell script. All goes fine until this line in the third one:

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
```

It throws this error:

> TerminatingError(New-Object): "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE))." New-Object : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).

If I log into the same host and run the script, it works fine. So what could be causing it to fail creating the `word.application` object when Ansible runs it?

What I've tried:

I added `Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Officer.Interop.Word` before the line, I also tried changing the line to `$word = [Microsoft.Officer.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass]::new()`. Still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_privilege_escalation.html#become-flags-for-windows
try with different logon_type parameters:
interactive|batch| other

```
name: Running my-script.ps1
  win_shell: |
    D:\Repos\my-repo\my-script.ps1
  vars:
    ansible_become: true
    ansible_become_method: runas
    ansible_become_user: '{{ ansible_user }}'
    ansible_become_password: '{{ ansible_password }}'
    ansible_become_flags: logon_type=new_credentials logon_flags=netcredentials_only
```

If you don't have WinRM configured, it's time to configure it.

```
$c = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName $(hostname) -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My -notafter $(Get-Date).AddYears(3)
winrm create winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS "@{Hostname=`"$hostname`";CertificateThumbprint=`"$($c.ThumbPrint)`"}"
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="WinRM-HTTPS" dir=in localport=5986 protocol=TCP action=allow
winrm set winrm/config/service/auth '@{Basic="true"}'
winrm set winrm/config/client/auth '@{Basic="true"}'
```

Connection parameters:

```
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_user: '{{ local_user }}'
ansible_password: '{{ local_user_password }}'
ansible_winrm_transport: basic
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
ansible_shell_type: "powershell"
```

For a domain user:

```
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_user: '{{ domain_user }}' 
ansible_password: '{{ domain_user_password }}'
ansible_winrm_transport: ntlm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
ansible_shell_type: "powershell"
```

*domain_user - domen\user