# Unable to create the Word.Application COM object remotely via Ansible

Tags: powershell, ansible, com

I have an Ansible task that runs a PowerShell script on a Windows 10 host. In this PowerShell script, it opens a Microsoft Word document and then exports it as a PDF.

The script is failing trying to create the `Word.Application` COM object:

```
$word = New-Object -COMObject Word.Application
```

It's throwing this error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).

This works when I log in and run it manually from the console.

I found [this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component/d801f311-cc39-4d83-8058-a209ef8f97cf) with the same error and tried the steps in the proposed solution (opening `dcomcnfg` and opening up all the Access and Launch and Activation permissions in the COM security), but I'm still getting the same error.

Does anyone know how I can get this working *or* if there's a better way to convert Word documents to PDF via PowerShell without using COM?

Comment: CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE just means Word (the COM "server" in this case) reported an error. There's no other way than COM to program Word itself, otherwise there are libraries out there (usually commercial ones) that can convert Word to PDF w/o COM and without Word at all.

Answer (score 0):

See: [PowerShell script works when run manually, but fails creating word.application object when initiated by Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75973591/powershell-script-works-when-run-manually-but-fails-creating-word-application-o)

The `Word.Application` COM object requires an interactive session to function properly, which might not be available when running the script remotely via Ansible. Adjust the logon type parameters in your Ansible playbook:

```
- name: Running my-script.ps1
  win_shell: |
    D:\\Repos\\my-repo\\my-script.ps1
  vars:
    ansible_become: true
    ansible_become_method: runas
    ansible_become_user: '{{ ansible_user }}'
    ansible_become_password: '{{ ansible_password }}'
    ansible_become_flags: logon_type=new_credentials logon_flags=netcredentials_only
```

Try this and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I received the same error with this also. I tried all different `logon_type`s and `logon_flags` from [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_privilege_escalation.html#become-flags-for-windows) with no luck. Does that work for you?